# Difference between vmware-clarity version 8 and vmware-clarity version 11(latest)

Tags: vmware-clarity

The vmware-clarity version 8 when upgraded to the latest version the wizard look and feel gets changed. How to retain it? What exactly changed in the latest version?

Comment: Are you looking for https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news?

Answer (score 0):

The Wizard component in Clarity has changed significantly since v0.9. You can check what changed from here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.9.0

Comment: Thanks JSDriller.